# Crash when running a .NET 3.5 app on .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, clr, compatibility

Our application is built using WinForms on .NET 3.5

This was tested specifically on Windows XP, although i am not sure whether it is OS related.

Whenever i run it on a machine with .NET 4 only, it will crash, saying that it cannot find the .NET assemblies versioned 3.5.

I am wondering why this does not happen automatically. For example, some 3rd party libraries install a policy of some sort, that when a newer version is installed, it will be used, even if your application was compiled against an older version.

**UPDATE:** The exact error message is:

**"Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application".**

My questions are:

1. Why is this not the same with the .NET framework?
2. The solution is to add the  element in the configuration file? Any other solutions?

Comment: I think the 3.5 (.net 2) CLR and the .net4 CLR run side by side so you need 3.5 runtime installed if you want to run older apps

Comment: Does it work when you install .net 3.5 and .net 4.0?

Comment: @EmmieGabrielleLewis yes, it does.

Comment: I typically configure my machines to include all versions of the framework.  I typically don't have issues.  Trying to run your application without the framework presents dependency issues.  Be safe and include the framework with your application as a prerequisite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your computer has no .NET 3.5 installed there is no CLR to start for your app. .NET 4.0 is not automatically used for your app because of potential compatibility issues. First test that your app does run with .NET 4.0 and then add this section to your app.config to tell the CLR to prefer running .NET 4.0 if present.

```
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

If .NET 4 is not present as fallback the CLR version against which you application was compiled against is used as fallback. If all fails you get the message "Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application".

Comment: Are there any downsides of using such configuration?

Comment: If your app does run with .net 4.0 there are no downsides.

Answer (score 3):

In general, that should *not* be the case:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx
>
> Backward compatibility means that an application developed for a
>   particular version of a platform will run on later versions of that
>   platform. The .NET Framework tries to maximize backward compatibility:
>   Source code written for one version of the .NET Framework should
>   compile on later versions of the .NET Framework, and binaries that run
>   on one version of the .NET Framework should behave identically on
>   later versions of the .NET Framework.
>
> ...
>
> The .NET Framework 4 is backward-compatible with applications that
>   were built with the .NET Framework versions 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5. In
>   other words, applications and components built with previous versions
>   of the .NET Framework will work on the .NET Framework 4.

SUGGESTIONS:

1) Read these links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd889541.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461502.aspx

2) See if you can reproduce the problem with a minimal .Net 3.5 Winforms app

3) Cut/paste the exact error message, and any relevant code (e.g. from your standalone app)

4) Failing all else, consider adding `<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" >` to your CLR startup configuration.  I would *not* recommend this as anything but a temporary workaround:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h.aspx

Comment: @liortal - besides giving us the exact error message and posting code (if possible), please also tell us the OS where this is failing.  I assume "Windows 7".  Thank you in advance...

Comment: I was also under the impression of what you specify in your answer, however your answer contradicts other answers here (by Alois Kraus).

Comment: Hi - Thank you for updating your post.  The problem is XP - if you ran your .Net 3.5 app on Vista, Win7 or Server 2008, it would probably work fine.  But since you're running on XP, you must either install .Net 3.5 (no necessarily a bad idea) and/or modify your app config.  Win7 has the CLRs pre-installed.

Answer (score 1):

.NET 4.0 introduce new CLR. So basicly having 4.0 doesn't help much in running 3.5 apps.
[It has been already mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148833/will-net-4-0-include-a-new-clr-or-keep-with-version-2-0)

Comment: Yes, .Net 4.0 has a new CLR.  But most environments running .Net 4.0 *should* be backward compatible.  There's something the OP is missing here...

Comment: I am confused whether .NET 4 (or CLR 4) should support running 3.5 or not then (without explicit configuration off course).