# VS Setup Project Requires .NET 2.0, .NET 4.0 is installed

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a `Setup Project` for a .NET 2.0 service.

If I'm not mistaken .NET is Backward Compatible, so a Server with .NET 4.0 should be able to run this service. The `Setup Project`'s Lauch Condition contains .NET 2.0 as requirement, and the setup won't install because it says it needs .NET 2.0 installed even though .NET 4.0 is installed.

How can I make the setup project allow installation if the server has .NET 2.0 or higher?

Comment: .NET v2 through v3.5 have the same CLR version, .NET v4 introduces the next CLR version. So you want v3.5 installed on the server alongside with v4.0 - otherwise see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10632225/11683.

Comment: Clearly the problem is that your installer is not backwards compatible.  Not much that Microsoft or SO users can do about that :)  And it isn't automatic, you need a .config file that says that you tested your service and that using 4.0 is okay.  `<supportedRuntime>` element.

Comment: I already have `<supportedRuntime>` configured in the project. And I just tried to change the required .NET version to `Any`, and the installation succeed, but is it ok to do this? I mean what if the server only have .NET 1.1?